Remove everything except files from list
I did find code on here but it only works on pdf files. if you want to remove all files and folders except for 3 of them(example a text file, bat file and exe file). this code only removes i think the pdf files. it says dir *pdf do I remove that line.
@echo off
set "exception1=testfile.EXE"
set "exception2=test remove.bat"

for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception1%" if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception2%" (
        echo Deleting "%%f"
        REM del "%%f"
    ) else (
        echo Keeping "%%f"
    )
)

i did try to execute the code but it did not remove the files from the dir on desktop

I also have this code but it only deletes files by extension and not specific name
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "folder[path]=%cd%"
SET "ext[exclude]=.exe .bat"

PUSHD "%folder[path]%"
FOR %%# in (*.*) DO (
    IF "!ext[exclude]!" == "!ext[exclude]:%%~x#=!" (
        DEL /F /Q "%%#"
    )
)
POPD


EXIT /B


You need to be very specific about your task requirements. Currently the title states "remove everything", however the code examples you've submitted seem only to be dealing with some files in the current working directory, not all files, and certainly not directories.

1. Your first code above is not reliable as I described at this comment. 2. The solution to your problem is in my answer that starts with: "this method works correctly no matters the number of files"; just use: set "exception=|testfile.EXE|test remove.bat|test.txt|" and change *.pdf by *.* PS Include a link to the code you use in a question...

@Aacini, that code also does not capture all files either, hence tha need for the OP to [Edit] their question and confirm their actual requirements.

The filemask *.pdf means "all files whose names end .pdf (case-insensitive), so that is why only .pdf files were processed. *,* means "all files". so if you want to process all files, then change the filemask. BUT
if you do that, the code you show won't do what you evidently anticipate.
Your if condition is
if not condition1 [then] if not condition2 [then] dothisifneitherconditionistrue 
else dothisifcondition1isfalseandcondition2isTRUE

that is, the else applies only to the last if, not to the ANDing of the two conditions, with the consequence that if the file found is testfile.exe then the keep message will not be displayed, neither will the deleting message.
I would echo the del command instead of REMming it out.
I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) as ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs (See for/f from the prompt for documentation) The documentation nominates only alphabetic characters. Some symbols appear to work, but are undocumented.
I also find negative logic (if not dothis else dothat) confusing, so I'd change to positive logic for maintainability's sake.
Matching against "%exception2%" will specifically match against a file named test remove.bat, not (test or remove.bat) - you mention 3 files to exempt, but defined only two...??
So, revision [untested]
@echo off
set "exception1=testfile.EXE"
set "exception2=test remove.bat"

for %%e in (*.*) do (
    set "keep="
    for %%y in (%exception1% %exception2%) do if /i "%%~nxe"=="%%~y" set "keep=y"
    if defined keep (
      echo Keeping "%%~e"
    ) else (
      echo Deleting "%%~e"
      echo DEL "%%~e"
    )
)

See Using Boolean
Note that I'm assuming that testfile.EXE, test and remove.bat are files to be exempted from the deletion.
if testfile.EXE and test remove.bat are files to be exempted from the deletion., then
set "exception2="test remove.bat""

This will assign the strings testfile.EXE and "test remove.bat" to %%e. %%~e will remove the quotes.
Applying these principles, reading the documentation (for /? from the prompt) and perusing the thousands of examples on SO should allow you to adapt the second piece of code to do whatever you want - but for safety's sake, ECHO del to show the command instead of executing it, and use a copy of the target for testing.

Correction to the above: On a Windows OS, with 8.3 short filenames enabled, (the default), the filemask *.pdf matches files whose extensions begin with .pdf (case-insensitive). That means *.pdf would also match .PDFX files. More importantly for %%e in (*.*) do ... or shorter for %%e in (*) do ..., completely ignores files with, for instance, -Hidden attributes. That is important here because the question specifically states "Remove everything except files from list". I have implied it already in a couple of comments, but it is important to highlight it isn't "everything".

@compo: I believe that short filenames are actually turned OFF by default in the past few versions.

I have a customer unit here Magoo, upon which I've clean installed, (on a formatted disk), Windows 11 Home 23H2, and Dir with /X shows 8.3 names.

@Compo: I recall researching this issue when I had a problem where 8.3 names were not being generated. I forget the details, but after some research, I found https://superuser.com/a/1505235/229204 which seemed to work. I'll draw your attention to the statement in that article, Since Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 newly formatted volumes will have 8.3 name generation disabled by default. This is probably the situation in your PC and the following paragraph. So, I'd conclude that your experience is with the system drive. I'll let you and phuclv slug it out... :)
